# Add child property failure to child

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, fluentvalidation

I'm new with FluentValidation.

I have two classes

```
public class A
{
    public B Prop { get; set; }
}

public class B 
{
    public decimal? Example { get; set; }
    public decimal? Example2 { get; set; }
}
```

And, i'm trying to validate `B` property inside `A` class.

If any property of `Prop` has validation error, i want set the first of the errors to prop object.

I'm trying some like this.

```
public class A : AbstractValidator<A>{    
    public A()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Prop.Example).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Prop.Example2).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Prop).Custom((obj,context) => {
            if(/* obj.Example or obj.Example2 has validation error */){
                context.AddFailure("message of any Example or Example2 errors");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Edit: some example of my view

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Prop, new { @class = "col-form-label" })
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Prop.Example, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
            <span class="input-group-text">@@</span>
        </div>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Prop.Example2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text">KVA</span>
        </div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Prop)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It should display some like this

[image]

Where the left input is Example, and the right one is Example 2.

So, if any of that both fail, the error message should be seen down (ValidationMessageFor)

I dont know how to validate `Prop` property errors inside a `RuleFor`

Is it possible this way? How can i do it?

Comment: Why do you want the validation message associated with `A.Prop` and not the individual properties in class `B`? can you post your view code showing how validation messages are being displayed? Can you describe why consolidating the errors under `Prop` is more desirable? You are fighting how FluentValidation was meant to work.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I updated the answer with the view code, I am trying to do it, because I use the viewmodel for two inputs (which is displayed as 1) then, if any of the 2 does not fulfill the validation, it should show the error (being only 1)

Comment: You can use directly B class in your view. why have you not used it?

Comment: @HiteshKansagara Hello! I don't understand your question well, what do you mean by using class b in the view?

Comment: you are passing model in your view right? currently you are passing A instead of A you can pass B getting?

Comment: @HiteshKansagara Ohh, i understand, the `A` class have more properties that i dont show because are irrelevant to de question :P

Comment: you just need to make both property of B class required right?

Comment: @HiteshKansagara yes, but i neet to ModelState shows error, for both B propertys and, the property itself (Prop)

Comment: add required attribute on b class properties. what happen if you put B class properties required?

Comment: @HiteshKansagara I tried to do it with, setting the validator, and both propertys are required correctly, but the `Prop` itself are not showing error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could *probably* get this working, but you might have an easier time by creating a validator for class `B` and then putting both validation messages in the UI right next to each other:

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Prop, new { @class = "col-form-label" })
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Prop.Example, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text">%</span>
            <span class="input-group-text">@@</span>
        </div>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Prop.Example2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text">KVA</span>
        </div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            @* Validation messages for both properties of class "B" *@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Prop.Example)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Prop.Example2)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ty for answer! I think about that posibility, but my problem was that the message could be so long, so i want to show only one if any of both fail, is possible to make it work inside the view?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use documentation of FluentValidation to create your own validator for class *B*. 
https://fluentvalidation.net/start#creating-your-first-validator

Then in main scope of function you can simply call that validator for class B.

Comment: Hi, ty for the answer, I tried that, the problem is that I don't get the error added to the Props property, that way, it is only added to Props.Example and Props.Example2